# Writing to a new file in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, file

I have a Spring Boot application running in an Azure App Service. The application uses `FileUtils.writeStringToFile` from `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` to write a string to a new file:

```
private String staticPath = "/static";

[...]

public void uploadFileContent(String content) throws Exception {
        try {
            File dir = new File(staticPath);
            if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
            String relativePath = DateFormatUtils.format(new Date(), Constants.DateFormatTemp.YYYYMM_SPRIT);
            String newFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + UUID.randomUUID();
            File fileDir = new File(dir, relativePath);
            if (!fileDir.exists()) fileDir.mkdirs();
            File newFile = new File(fileDir, newFileName + Constants.Split.SPOT + "csv");

            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newFile, content);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Locally it works, but if I run it in Azure then I get:

> java.io.IOException: File 'example.csv' could not be created

The exception occurs at the last line of the try block, i.e. `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(newFile, content);`

Does writing to file system in Azure require certain special operations?

Comment: Could you please provide the code you use to create file and the path?

Comment: Yes, sure. I edited the question.

Comment: Does it work if you change the staticPath to, say, D:\home\test?